# Multiple In App Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have developed an app (iOS) that sells around 10 products. Is it possible to for the user to select multiple products and make a combined transaction?

Comment: No, you can buy only single product at a time.

Comment: But what you can do is let the user select the multiple in-apps say 5 products and then make 5 in-app calls to apple server.

Comment: I think you should make separate packages of multiple products for ex. make a new product which unlocks product 1 & 2 and an other product which unlocks product 1,2 & 5.

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore, Can all those 5 in-app calls be done on a single button click?

Comment: that's your logic, if you want to call all those inapp call in single click, it's just a code, how you call it, it will do the same

Comment: Is it possible to obtain a single receipt for multiple products?